# how to reduce the size of a binary matrix and preserve all the ones in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a 648 * 2340 matrix which contains ones and zeros but mostly zeros. i would like to reduce the matrix to 216 * 780, which is 9 times smaller in terms of matrix elements. That being said I need to divide the big matrix into many 3 * 3 matrices which eventually collapse into one element. The value of the element should be one if there exists one in the 3 * 3 matrices and 0 otherwise. What are the approaches to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done this way:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
m1, n1 = 12, 12 # dimensions input array
a1 = np.random.choice((0, 1), size=(m1, n1), replace=True, p=(.9, .1)) # input array
m2, n2 = 4, 4 # dimensions output array
a2 = np.zeros((m2, n2), dtype=int) # output array
s1, s2 = int(m1/m2), int(n1/n2) # dimensions 'subset array'
for i, x in enumerate(np.linspace(0, m1, int(m1/s1), endpoint=False, dtype=int, axis=0)):
    for j, y in enumerate(np.linspace(0, n1, int(n1/s1), endpoint=False, dtype=int, axis=0)):
        if a1[x:x+s1, y:y+s2].sum() > 0:
            a2[i, j] = 1
```

Generated matrix `a1`:

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Output matrix `a2`:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

When needed, you can easily change the size of the input array `a1` by changing the values for `m1` and `n1` and for the output array `a2` by changing `m2` and `n2` (in your case: `648`, `2340`, `216`, `780`).
Probabilities for `0` and `1` values in the input array `a1` are set to `.9` and `.1` in the example but can be changed too.

Answer (score 0):

Use sparse matrix representation.
It is representation of matrix where only entries containing non null values (1 in your case) are stored.

```python
sparseMatrix = [[0,0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0]]
 
# initialize size as 0
size = 0
 
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(5):
        if (sparseMatrix[i][j] != 0):
            size += 1
 
# number of columns in compactMatrix(size) should
# be equal to number of non-zero elements in sparseMatrix
rows, cols = (3, size)
compactMatrix = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
 
k = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(5):
        if (sparseMatrix[i][j] != 0):
            compactMatrix[0][k] = i
            compactMatrix[1][k] = j
            compactMatrix[2][k] = sparseMatrix[i][j]
            k += 1
 
for i in compactMatrix:
    print(i)
```

For more info : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Comment: thank you for the response! Sparse matrix is interesting and I'll definitely have a look at it. However your method changes a 4*5 matrix to a 3*6 one and I am not so sure what compactMatrix[0][k] = i, compactMatrix[1][k] = j, compactMatrix[2][k] = sparseMatrix[i][j] these three lines do.

Comment: I think the number don't matter here. It is just for giving examples. You can also check this. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sparse-matrix-representation/